# Bypassing BearerStrategy in Nestjs Guard and Strategy

Tags: authentication, nestjs, passport.js

I have the following Nestjs global guard for my app:

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Reflector } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard extends AuthGuard(
    ["azure-ad"]
) {
    public constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {
        super();
    }

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const isPublic = this.reflector.get<boolean>(
            "isPublic",
            context.getHandler()
        );

        if (isPublic) {
            return true;
        }
        
        const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        await super.logIn(request);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And the following strategy for auth:

```
import {
  BearerStrategy,
  IBearerStrategyOption,
  ITokenPayload,
  VerifyCallback,
} from "passport-azure-ad"
import {
  Inject,
  Injectable,
  OnModuleInit,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from "@nestjs/common"
import passport = require("passport")
import env from "../../../config"
import { User } from "modules/users/users.interface"
import { UsersService } from "modules/users/users.service"

const tenantId = env.TENANT_ID
const clientID = env.CLIENT_ID || ""

const azureCredentials: IBearerStrategyOption = {
  identityMetadata: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
  clientID,
  validateIssuer: true,
  issuer: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/v2.0`,
  audience: clientID,
}

@Injectable()
export class AzureAdStrategy extends BearerStrategy implements OnModuleInit {
  onModuleInit() {
    passport.use("azure-ad", this)
  }

  constructor(@Inject(UsersService) private usersService: UsersService) {
    super(
      azureCredentials,
      async (token: ITokenPayload, done: VerifyCallback) => {
        if (Date.now() / 1000 > token.exp) {
          return done(new UnauthorizedException("access token is expired"))
        }

        const tokenUsername = token?.preferred_username?.slice(0, 9)
        const tokenAppId = !tokenUsername && token?.azp

        if (!tokenUsername && !tokenAppId) {
          return done(new UnauthorizedException("Missing User"))
        }

        let user: User

        if (tokenUsername) {
          try {
            user = await this.usersService.getUser(tokenUsername)
            if (!user) {
              return done(new UnauthorizedException("User is not recognized"))
            }
          } catch (err) {
            return done(err)
          }
        }
        return done(null, user, token)
      },
    )
  }
}
```

This works great. I need to have a backdoor logic for my application, so it bypasses the azureAD authorization if a certain header is sent in the request, lets say `req.is_bypass`

What's the best way to achive that? is it even possible or do i need to use a different logic for backdoor auth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LoginGuard`'s `canActivate` you have access to the `ExecutionContext` object, which can be used to get the current request. After your check of  the `isPublic` metadata you can add the check you're looking to do

```js
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Reflector } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard extends AuthGuard(
    ["azure-ad"]
) {
    public constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {
        super();
    }

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const isPublic = this.reflector.get<boolean>(
            "isPublic",
            context.getHandler()
        );

        if (isPublic) {
            return true;
        }

        const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
        if (req.is_bypass) {
          return true;
        }
        
        const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        await super.logIn(request);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I needed to access req.headers before I could get my specific header, but this worked great :)